# How to pass data from controller to jQuery/CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, controller, coffeescript

Below I have the controller action that will get both the proper campaign, as well as that campaigns associated relationships with its locations in the campaign_locations table as:

```
def edit
    @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
    @campaign_locations = CampaignLocation.where(campaign_id: :id).pluck(:location_id)
end
```

and campaign_location table has the layout as:

[image]

What I need to do is pass the resulting data from the object `@campaign_location` into the jQuery/coffeecscript file `campaigns.js.coffee` to prerocessp prior to the campaigns/edit/:id page load, but have seen nowhere on how to enable such actions with a jQuery object.

**How can I pass an object directly from the controller to the correct pages jQuery/CoffeeScript?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem to expose your instance variables to your JavaScript/Coffeescript. There's also a good [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript) on how to use this gem. Hope this helps.

Comment: perfect solution, had no idea this was such a popular gem